# How to a foreign key points to a composed primary key?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table Login which has login and password fields. Both are primary key.

And I have a table Character. Which login can have many characters. So how does the foreign key works?

How do I create foreign key inside Character table to Login?

Should I create 2 fields as foreign keys inside Character table to point to Login?

**Thanks!**

Comment: Why is `login, password` a composite primary key rather than just `login`? Can one `login` have multiple passwords? `password` doesn't seem stable enough to be part of a PK (IMO)

Comment: What is the interest to have the password a Primary key!? What happen if a login changes is password to another one used by the other same login? That DB implementation seems weird...

Comment: The password field should not be part of the primary key. If both login id and password are part of the primary key, then the password becomes part of the identity of the account, and that is bad for a lot of reasons. Also, it means that login ids would not be unique in the system.

Comment: Thats an excellent question. I guess I'm wrong hehe. Anyway, I would like to know considering that right. Thanks, I will review it.

Comment: @Jeffrey L Whitledge: "it means that login ids would not be unique in the system" -- there was no evidence of that. In fact, it would be a fair assumption that `login id` is indeed a key and that the OP's chosen (possibly ill-chosen) PK is a superkey.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the following in your table creation or alter script:

```
create table character (
  field1 varchar(30),
  ...,
  login varchar(12),
  password varchar(128),
  foreign key (login, password) references login (login, password)
)
```

Now, this said, it seems odd to include password in your primary key of your login table.  I'd recommend just having a primary key on the login table, or perhaps even a surrogate key (integer identity).  Using the approach of including login and password, you'll allow multiple signups under the same login.  That may be okay, but it seems like you could actually create a situation where a single user accidentally creates multiple logins.  Also, it will make it more difficult to manage lost password recovery.  Lastly, each time that the password changes (and the user could change it at any time), it will have to be updated in each referring field, and will drastically complicate password changes.

Comment: Thanks, but in case of my strategy is right (which is not), I still don't understand how to work with this situation. How could I add a new instance (object) inside Character table? Tell me the sql query, thanks!

Comment: @seva - Your character table would need to contain both columns (`login, password`)

Comment: I updated the query, so you can see how this works.  I personally am a big fan of natural keys and composite foreign keys (when the key fields are stable and won't change!), versus surrogate keys.  But in this case, I really agree with the comments that password probably shouldn't be in the key.  It is definitely not "stable" as the user can change it at will.